# Ruby on Rails - Edit/Update creating new records instead of updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have seen the other links to this similar question but none of them seem to work in my case.

My update action is creating new records in mysql database

My app consists of 3 models

1. `FashionModel`
2. `ModelProfile` and
3. `Measurement`

They are defined as follows:

```
class FashionModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  has_one :model_profile
  has_one :measurement
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :model_profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :measurement
end


class ModelProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :fashion_model
end


class Measurement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :fashion_model
end
```

The `fashion_model_controller.rb` is as follows:

```
class FashionModelsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @fashion_model = FashionModel.new
  end

  def create
    @fashion_model = FashionModel.new(fashion_models_sign_up_params)
    if @fashion_model.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to Meriad"
      session[:fashion_model_id] = @fashion_model.id
      redirect_to edit_fashion_model_path(@fashion_model)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @fashion_model = FashionModel.find(params[:id])
    @fashion_model.build_model_profile
    @fashion_model.build_measurement
  end

  def update
    @fashion_model = FashionModel.find(params[:id])
    if @fashion_model.update(fashion_models_edit_params)
      flash[:success] = "Saved!"
      redirect_to fashion_model_path(@fashion_model)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def show
    @fashion_model = FashionModel.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

The `fashion_model_edit_params` are

```
def fashion_models_edit_params
    params.require(:fashion_model).permit(:first_name,
                                          :last_name,
                                          :email,
                                          :password,
                                          model_profile_attributes: [:id,
                                                                     :location,
                                                                     :bio, :gender,
                                                                     :phone_number,
                                                                     :rate,
                                                                     :profile_image,
                                                                     :birthdate],
                                          measurement_attributes: [:id,
                                                                   :feet,
                                                                   :inches,
                                                                   :bust,
                                                                   :waist,
                                                                   :hips,
                                                                   :dress,
                                                                   :shoes,
                                                                   :hair,
                                                                   :eyes])
  end
```

I want something on these lines:

- The fashion model signs up to the app through `new.html.erb` (which is stored in the `fashion_models` table)
- The `index.html.erb` contains a list of all `fashion_models` with an option to edit information (update their profile)
- The `edit.html.erb` contains fields from the `model_profiles` table as well as the `measurements` table, both of which have the foreign keys to the `fashion_models` table.

My `fashion_models/new.html.erb` template is pretty straightforward containing `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `password`.

My `fashion_models/edit.html.erb` template is something like:

```
<%= form_for @fashion_model do |f| %>
  # fashion_model fields here

  <%= f.fields_for :model_profile do |t| %>
    # model_profile fields here
  <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for :measurement do |t| %>
    # measurement fields here
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Now, whenever I edit a `fashion_model/:id`, the `model_profile` and `measurement` create a new record in the database rather than updating the existing record. Also, when I am on the `Edit Profile` page, none of the fields pre populate with the existing data. I have to manually enter all the data again.

First, I thought it was because of the `build` methods, but when I remove them, the `fields_for` do not display.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out a way to do this. Hope it helps someone.

My problem was that I had 2 `fields_for` inside one `form_for` and I needed to update 2 models with to these forms.

I tired using callbacks like `after_action :create_model_profile` and `after_action :create_measurement`. And in both of these methods I tried to save `fashion_model_id` as the `:id` of the newly created `fashion_model`.

But since callbacks are considered as **code smells**, I wanted a better solution.

Instead of creating a `form_for @fashion_models`, I wrote a helper method as follows

```
# app/helpers/form_helper.rb
module FormHelper
  def setup_fashion_model(fashion_model)
    fashion_model.model_profile ||= ModelProfile.new
    fashion_model.measurement ||= Measurement.new
    fashion_model
  end
end
```

and in my `form_for` I used something like

```
form_for(setup_fashion_model(@fashion_model)) do |f|
  ...
end
```

This created a new instance of `ModelProfile` and `Measurement` if it did not persist in the database.

It then of course solved the problem of pre populating the fields which contained data.

This was it. Simple solution, but I'd been there scratching my head.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably making a mess with their routes.

It works like this:

- `form_for` calls `@fashion_model.new_record?`
- **IF True:** It will submit to `POST /fashion_model`, and create an object.
- **IF False:** It will submit to `PUT /fashion_model/:id`, and update an object.

As you can see, it just depends if the object already exists in the database or not. So, check again, where you are using the `form_for` and which object you are passing it.

For questions with the routes, see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I don't think I messed up with the routes. I have a resources for fashion_models.
As you said I have a post request for create and put/patch for update

Comment: @PradyumnaShembekar If `form_for` is creating objects, it is because it's assuming that the object isn't in the database, you can print the page to make sure, put before the form: `<h1><%= @fashion_model.persisted? %></h1>`

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I was just trying that through the rails console. My concern now is that since I am redirecting my /new or sign up page directly to my edit page, I am not able to instantiate ModelProfile and Measurement. I tried creating them before ending the new action and setting the fashion_model_id to @fashion_model.id But still couldn't do that. Do you think a before action can satisfy this need

Comment: I do not know if I understand, but in fact, Rails is already doing it to you through the `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. Your code is doing it correctly. I think you should remove `@fashion_model.build_model_profile` and `@fashion_model.build_measurement` lines from `edit`, because this lines are building two new clean objects.

Comment: If I remove that, my fields_for forms do not show up

Comment: The error persists if you replace `f.fields_for :model_profile` by `f.fields_for @fashion_model.model_profile`? Remember remove last two lines from `FashionModelsController#edit`.

Comment: I removed the `build` methods from the `FashionModelsController#edit` and already have `f.fields_for :model_profile`, yet nothing appears in the form. I tried using the `@fashion_model.model_profile` which in this case naturally throws an error.

Comment: See: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for for `fields_for` issues.